# What is the best way to track IR led?

Tags: infrared, video, tracking

I want to build an interactive whiteboard which uses an infrared ped. I want to use a camera to track IR position on the projection screen.
I plan to keep the camera a little further away from the laptop. So what will be the best way (wifi/bluetooth/usb) to get the continous video input from camera? I am worried that if the video input is slow then processing (using openCV) the image to track the IR position will be slow. I want to track the IR pen in real time.

What would be the fastest way for to achieve this? Should I buy a IP camera or build one from raspberry pi? Or Usb webcam will be better?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think your question is on-topic here. This site deals with electronics design questions, not usage or shopping recommendations.

Comment: I would choose a monochromatic camera with the ability to block daylight with a filter and pass IR BW.  THe term “real-time” must be defined in terms of latency for the entire process of frame grab, and decimation to binary with an adjustable threshold In order to block the projected and ambient light and convert the IR when directed and reflected to a visible target that might be recorded for merging later.  I think a visible light might be needed to aim properly. Frame rate ought to synchronized at some point in the process to reduce aliasing and latency.

Comment: But you ought to define latency in pixel motion per frame including processing time.

Comment: Google "motion detection"

Answer (score 1):

If you're just building a few units and not a big scaler product, I would change the plan. Check out Nintendo Wii IR camera - they contain IR camera and output the position of one or more IR emitters.

By using a ready module you can save your time to build the interactive functionality instead of building a camera system and OpenCV processing and integration.

Comment: Oh yeah that's exactly what was in my mind. Wii camera will track an IR emitter so easily !

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably don't need a high frame rate to track the pen with sufficient accuracy I would say that any camera interface works fine.

However a USB3.1 camera would be the safest choice.

If you do need a very high framerate then a [cameralink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Link) connection is the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even being off topic. I guess I'll go with usb webcam.